# Test Case and Testing google app engine

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine

I have developed a application in google app engine **[python]** 
How can i test it with witting some kind of script?
I have tried *gaeunit* . Is there is any other option ?

Suppose i have following type of Form

[image]

How can i write test script for this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not unit testing - unit testing is when you test basic units of your code for proper operation, without running it in production environment. What you are doing is functional testing.

I recommend you take a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).